# Intellisense for JavaScript but using C# Project (ToolTip)

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, tooltip, intellisense

im developing a code-editor and now working with the intellisense for javascript something like this:

[image: http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/WhatsNew2010v1/i/asp-intelllisense-individual.png]

i already have the code for tooltip same as placing after "(" but i dunno what/where data to input inside everytooltip for every keyword for javascript .

now my question was where can i find those list of syntax and description display for j.s tooltips?

thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe you need some kind of attribute (one kind of metadata)?

Comment: @KingKing what do you mean sir?

Comment: where can i find those syntax and description display for j.s tooltips?

Comment: Do you mean these articles? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb385682.aspx

Comment: @Diryboy i dunno exactly if thats what im looking for coz theres a lot of types of tooltip for a normal code editor ... what i want was after a specific keyword and i press "(" ... exactly what the image shows above